# Convert polygon shapefile geometry to text file in a specific layout, including number of nodes per polygon

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I'm trying to convert a large shapefile (more than 20,000 polygons) to a text file to use in a modelling software. It needs to be in a specific format which is number of nodes, followed by all x coordinates followed by all y coordinates with each polygon on a new line (Pictured below) (first line is total number of polygons).

[image: screenshot of correct text file]

Currently I am using QGIS 3.6.3 and saving the shapefile as a CSV using WKT geometry. This however does not include the number of nodes and coordinates are formatted as xy xy. Please note that I am not constrained to QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this script:

open your python console in qgis and copy/paste the following code:

```
def extract_polygons(shapefile,lyrname,textfile):
    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(shapefile,lyrname, 'ogr')
    ft = lyr.getFeatures()
    with open(textfile, 'w') as o:
        for feature in ft:
            geom = feature.geometry()
            polygon = geom.asPolygon()
            xs = []
            ys = []
            for point in polygon[0]:
                xs.append(str(point[0]))
                ys.append(str(point[1]))

            number_of_nodes = str(len(polygon[0]))
            x_coords = ' '.join(xs)
            y_coords = ' '.join(ys)
            o.write('{} {} {} \n'.format(number_of_nodes, x_coords, y_coords))
#example
extract_polygons('path/to/your/shapefile/test.shp','test','path/to/output/file.txt')
```

Keep in mind that due to the fact that the first and the last node of a polygon are the same there may be some sanity issues (ie. square buildings with 5 points)